# Android toolbar "залезает" под statusbar при попытке реализации навигационной панели

Tags: android, activity

В приложении мне нужно создать навигационную панель (Drawer), причём с условием, что панель не перекрывает Toolbar, как это сделано по умолчанию.
Во всех уроках в интернете написано, что нужно просто перенести AppBarLayout c вложенным Toolbar'ом из `app_bar_main.xml` в `activity_main.xml`, поместить их перед основным содержимым и обернуть в LinearLayout.

Я пытался сделать так, но при запуске приложения тулбар поднимается вверх и словно "залезает" под строку состояния. Выглядит это примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне сделать так, чтобы этого не было? Я уже по-всякому перепробовал.

Исходный код `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Может быть реализация в этом туториале поможет. Не перекрывает.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FDUjGUZRdao

Answer (score 1):

Просто добавьте в ваш `NavigationView` следующую строку.

```
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
```

Правда в руководстве по **Material Design** сказано, что **Navigation Drawer** должен располагаться поверх тулбара. И это правильно, потому что остается больше пространства под меню. И еще это возможно лишено смысла, потому что при открытом боковом меню, тулбар все равно становится неактивным.

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Попробуйте так.